# Bottomsheet layout like apple store

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to archive something like the picture below:

[image]

A view who appears from the bottom, something like `BottomSheet Dialog` from `Android`.

But I really don`t know how to do this. Is a native element? If no, how to do this?

Comment: This is not available as a built-in UI component, but you can use a `UIVisualEffectView` as a background and narrow `UIView`s as separators.

Comment: do you have a example? @the4kman

Comment: @LMaker try using this lib and customised accordingly - https://github.com/hryk224/Bottomsheet